# How do I create a dovetail background using CSS?

Tags: css, background-image

[image: Design from Client]

So a client gave me this design. The background is supposed to change when the different wood grain options are clicked - easy.  The part I'm scratching my head about is the middle with the dovetail?  It's not an easy problem.

I'm wondering how you would approach this.  Right now I'm thinking use CSS Grid and try to center the wood grain background images vertically and align them left.  Then I'll stack divs in the middle.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: I think it is not easy..

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** SO is a place for asking questions that can be answered, not discussed.

Comment: initial thought without any CSS to back it up. Why not generate the second image with the dove tail cut out as a transparent png and float the second div a negative left margin so it overlaps the first div. you would have to increase the left padding to accommodate the negative margin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and negative margins to achieve the dovetail

**rough working example:**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: darkred;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 15%, 0 0, 15% 0%, 85% 0%, 85% 40%, 95% 30%, 95% 70%, 85% 63%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 85%);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
  margin-left: -2.5em
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

There are many online generators to help with creating the clip-path.